# Python lengh of json is incorrect

Tags: json, python-2.7, urllib

My problem is that the length of the json object I load is wrong. It can not be 1, the data has a lot more objects.

How can I solve this problem?

This is the Code:

```
import urllib
import json

applesource = urllib.urlopen("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/AAPL%3AUS?timeFrame=1_YEAR")

appledata = json.load(applesource)

print appledata
print len(appledata)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pretty-print](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) the object:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(appledata)
```

and you'll quickly see that there is a single dictionary inside the `appledata` list:

```
[{u'dateTimeRanges': {},
  u'id': u'AAPL:US',
  u'lastPrice': 107.33,
  u'lastUpdateDate': u'2015-12-21',
  u'nyTradeEndTime': u'16:30:00.000',
  u'nyTradeStartTime': u'09:30:00.000',
  u'price': [{u'date': u'2014-12-22', u'value': 112.94},
             {u'date': u'2014-12-23', u'value': 112.54},
             {u'date': u'2014-12-24', u'value': 112.01},
             {u'date': u'2014-12-26', u'value': 113.99},
             {u'date': u'2014-12-29', u'value': 113.91},
             {u'date': u'2014-12-30', u'value': 112.52},
             {u'date': u'2014-12-31', u'value': 110.38},
             {u'date': u'2015-01-02', u'value': 109.33},
             {u'date': u'2015-01-05', u'value': 106.25},
             {u'date': u'2015-01-06', u'value': 106.26},
             {u'date': u'2015-01-07', u'value': 107.75},
             {u'date': u'2015-01-08', u'value': 111.89},
             {u'date': u'2015-01-09', u'value': 112.01},
             {u'date': u'2015-01-12', u'value': 109.25},
             {u'date': u'2015-01-13', u'value': 110.22},
             {u'date': u'2015-01-14', u'value': 109.8},
             {u'date': u'2015-01-15', u'value': 106.82},
             ...
             {u'date': u'2015-12-21', u'value': 107.33}],
  u'priceMinDecimals': 2,
  u'timeZoneOffset': -5}]
```

You've probably meant to check the prices:

```
prices = appledata[0]["price"] 
print(len(prices))  # prints 252
```

Comment: Thx now I got it, I wasn't aware of the dictionary, I am quite new to python. How can I extract only the price and date for the whole year?

Comment: @PedramShahlaifar iterate over prices: `for price in prices:  ...` - now on every iteration, get the `price["date"]` and `price["value"]`.

Answer (score 0):

`appledata` is a list with one element. The dictionary is `appledata[0]`.